# HTML text margin exceeds body

Tags: html, css, document-body

In my HTML, there is a body stretched across the height of the viewport, while in the viewport there is a div containing paragraphs of text. My text has some margin and because of that, it exceeds the body. 
I thought it was really strange, since the paragraph was a child of the div, which was a child of the body, that the paragraph's margin exceeded his parent. Is there a solution for this? (except removing the margin as I want to keep that)
Thanks in advance! 
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu0fn.png)
The blue stuff is actually the body (as this has been selected in the Inspector on the right. You see clearly it doesn't reach to the top of the page. 
My stuff:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "MavenPro";
  src: url('fonts/MavenPro-Medium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "MavenPro";
  src: url('fonts/MavenPro-Bold.ttf');
  font-weight: bold;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "MavenPro";
  background-image: url('../images/BIER.jpeg');
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

#nav {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mitem {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  background-color: #dea243;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ae4411;
}

.mitem:link {
  /*no css yet*/
}

.mitem:hover {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  background-color: #d2b651;
  color: #cccccc;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.mitem:active {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #ee7744;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0025ff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

a:hover {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  color: #0045ff;
}

a:active {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  color: #ff4444;
}

#content {
  /*no css yet*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#link">
        <li class="mitem">Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#link">
        <li class="mitem">Alcohol</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <p><a href="#link">Here is a link</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Share your code..

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to the CSS of your paragraph element and body element.

This will squeeze the paragraph element inside the body.

Comment: Add 'display: inline-block' to your '#content'. Problem Solved.

If you need to move down your first p element, just give a <br> before it & customize br's padding & margin to your wish.

Here: codepen.io/shreyansjain33/pen/ENyLrL

Answer (score 0):

EDIT/ADDITION:

The reason is your `p` tag - it's margin settings (10px). If you add this, the space above disappears:

```
p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVqMBV

unrelated note: `li`elements shouldn't be inside `a` tags, it has to be the other way round.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but sadly, this didn't work too, the space above the body became smaller, but still isn't gone. I don't know where I should add it, but I tried adding is to html, body, p and #content (that's the div where p is a child of)

Comment: the `*` is the universal selector: if you wwrite it as I wrote it, is is valid for *all* elements.

Comment: also, there can't be a "space above the body"  if you have "margin: 0" on `body` and `html`. Actually it's rather unclear what you are talking about, you should post your real code (the little code you have posted certainly can't show what you describe)

Comment: Please note the addtion to my answer, which solves that particular problem ("collapsing margins")

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. But what do I do when I want to have a margin on the first item in the div?

Comment: use padding instead, or  `position:relative` and a `top` setting for the offset

Comment: please mark my answer as correct or/and give it an upvote